# Черный экран у эмулируемого телефона в android studio

Tags: android, android-emulator

Пишу приложение на React Native и хочу протестировать его на эмуляторе в Android Studio, а у меня этот эмулятор не запускается просто появляется эмулируемый телефон с черным экраном.
Менял SDK, 3 раза переустановил все нужные плагины с учетом того что у меня процессор AMD, установил windows10 pro и настроил Hyper-V как надо.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Попробуйте еще пару пассов: проверьте, что у вас не используется антивирус (кромев строенного в десятую винду, на него можно не обращать внимания), и что среда разработки (откуда и запускается эмулятор, как я понимаю) запускается с правами администратора

Comment: Если нажать на эмуляторе на кнопку Вкл, то включится? (бывает такое, что он типа выключен)

Answer (score 1):

Была такая ситуация, причем snapshot давал картинку работающего экрана. Решение: В окне эмулятора три точки открыть 'Extended controls'->Settings->Advanced->OpenGL ES renderer. Autodetect заменил на Desktop native OpenGL
После перезагрузки эмулятора все заработало.
Android Studio ver. 2022.1.1